# Replacing specific Characters in an Image using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I have the next Image:

[image]

I want to find all the occurrences of an specific character, let's say "a", and then replacing it with another character, let's say "e"

This can be done in ***Python3*** using ***OpenCV*** and ***Numpy***, to do that I'm using the next two images in order to do template matching:

[image]
[image]

my code is the next:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('source_image.jpg') # Importing Source Image
imgray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Converting Source Image to Gray Scale

template_a = cv.imread('template_a.jpg') # Reading Template "a" Character
template_a_gray = cv.cvtColor(template_a, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Converting Template "a" Character to Gray Scale

template_e = cv.imread('template_e.jpg') # Reading Template "e" Character
template_e_gray = cv.cvtColor(template_e, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Converting Template "e" Character to Gray Scale

# Template Matching
w, h = template_a_gray.shape[::-1] # Obtaining Width and Height of Template "a" Character
res = cv.matchTemplate(imgray, template_a_gray, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) # Template Matching

threshold = 0.6
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(imgray, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), color=(255,255,255), thickness=cv.FILLED) # Removing Matched Template "a" Characters

    y_offset = pt[1]
    x_offset = pt[0]
    x_end = x_offset + template_e_gray.shape[1]
    y_end = y_offset + template_e_gray.shape[0]

    imgray[y_offset:y_end,x_offset:x_end] = template_e_gray # Pasting Template "e" Characters

filename = 'savedImage.jpg' 
cv.imwrite(filename, imgray) # Saving Image

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

When executed the result is:

[image]

The problem is that when zoom in, the pasted image isn't exactly the same as the template character for e

[image]
[image]

Blobs appear above and in the left of the original "e" template character. Why is this happening? How do I get rid of them?

***Edit:*** in Response of Christoph Rackwitz's Comment:

[image]

***Edit:*** Code fixed upon Christoph Rackwitz's Suggestions

Comment: run your code but leave this line out: `img[y_offset:y_end,x_offset:x_end] = template_e_resized` then you'll see what's left standing outside of your rectangle() call

Comment: It appears all white, it doesn't appear blobs or characters

Comment: can you add such an output to the question?

Comment: yeah, I have already done it

Comment: ah, you call `cv.resize` on your substitute! look at the result of that, it's using nearest neighbor in all likelihood! perhaps you shouldn't resize the thing, but simply paste it 1:1. if it happens to be smaller than the 'a' pattern, then let it be smaller. you're erasing the 'a' anyway with the rectangle() call

Comment: wait... that resize does nothing! at least, it should not do anything. you tell it to resize the thing to its own size! why did you do that? does the result have the same shape as the input?

Comment: I was having some problems when I didn't resize it, my code threw me some errors, but let me see

Comment: if you have errors, your errors stem from mixing grayscale and color arrays. they have different shapes. stick to all grayscale or all color. never ever use magic constants like `0` to imread. there's the `IMREAD_*` constants.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have already converted everything to grayscale and removed the resize function, but the blobs are still there

Answer (score 1):

This is because `template_e_gray` is pasted multiple times. Blobs are the edges of another `e` pasted just before. Print `pt` and see where `e` is pasted.

There are several ways to deal with this problem. The easiest way is to set the threshold to 0.8.

```py
threshold = 0.8
```

If this is sufficient, use this. But may not be sufficient for some applications because the threshold needs to be tuned per image.

Another way is to fill white with one pixel larger.

```py
imgray[y_offset - 1:y_end + 1, x_offset - 1:x_end + 1] = 255
imgray[y_offset:y_end, x_offset:x_end] = template_e_gray  # Pasting Template "e" Characters
```

This is easy too, but inefficient, misaligned, and may not work with large images.

My recommandation is to use non maximum suppression (NMS). NMS is a technique commonly used in object detection that delete all overlapping rectangles except the one with the highest score.

Borrowing the implementation from [here](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/b612190f279da3c11dd8b1396dd5e72779f8e463/lib/utils/nms.py), this is the complete code.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


# https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/lib/utils/nms.py
def nms(dets, thresh):
    x1 = dets[:, 0]
    y1 = dets[:, 1]
    x2 = dets[:, 2]
    y2 = dets[:, 3]
    scores = dets[:, 4]

    areas = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
    order = scores.argsort()[::-1]

    keep = []
    while order.size > 0:
        i = order[0]
        keep.append(i)
        xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[order[1:]])
        yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[order[1:]])
        xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[order[1:]])
        yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[order[1:]])

        w = np.maximum(0.0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
        h = np.maximum(0.0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)
        inter = w * h
        ovr = inter / (areas[i] + areas[order[1:]] - inter)

        inds = np.where(ovr <= thresh)[0]
        order = order[inds + 1]

    return keep


img = cv.imread('source_image.jpg')  # Importing Source Image
imgray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Converting Source Image to Gray Scale

template_a = cv.imread('temp/template_a.jpg')  # Reading Template "a" Character
template_a_gray = cv.cvtColor(template_a, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Converting Template "a" Character to Gray Scale

template_e = cv.imread('temp/template_e.jpg')  # Reading Template "e" Character
template_e_gray = cv.cvtColor(template_e, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Converting Template "e" Character to Gray Scale

# Template Matching
w, h = template_a_gray.shape[::-1]  # Obtaining Width and Height of Template "a" Character
res = cv.matchTemplate(imgray, template_a_gray, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)  # Template Matching

threshold = 0.6
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
top, left = loc
score = res[loc]
iou_threshold = 0.5
matched_boxes = np.array([left, top, left + w, top + h, score]).T
valid_indices = nms(matched_boxes, iou_threshold)
boxes = matched_boxes[valid_indices]
boxes = boxes[..., :-1].astype(int)

for pt in boxes:
    print(pt)
    cv.rectangle(imgray, pt[:2], pt[2:], color=(255, 255, 255),
                 thickness=cv.FILLED)  # Removing Matched Template "a" Characters

    y_offset = pt[1]
    x_offset = pt[0]
    x_end = x_offset + template_e_gray.shape[1]
    y_end = y_offset + template_e_gray.shape[0]

    imgray[y_offset:y_end, x_offset:x_end] = template_e_gray  # Pasting Template "e" Characters

filename = 'temp/savedImage.jpg'
cv.imwrite(filename, imgray)  # Saving Image

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works perfectly as expected, but you will see the following results. See the area circled in red.

[image: Result with NMS still have some blobs]

This is a trace of `a`, not `e`.
This is caused by the difference in size between `a` in the image and `a` in the template, and is unrelated to the original issue. I mentioned this because I thought you would suspect that the same issue remains.

Comment: good catch! I did not think of multiple adjacent detections. -- matchTemplate returns raster data. NMS on that can be accomplished by grayscale dilation and equality comparison.

Comment: I printed pt and there were many instances of what I thought there should be, so I didn't understand very well that part of the code, I was following the Template Matching article of OpenCV Documentation and that's how they do it. I guess the left traces of "a" might be removed detecting all the contours in the image and removing those who have an area smaller than a certain value. I'm going to further study my original problem and study and test your approach, thanks